# How to test frontend app step by step by scenario?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, frontend, integration-testing

We have a web project and the main business flow is going through the chain of processes (conveyor). We don't have any automatic tests for front. So, to test we use our "hands".

What I want to do is to create some auto test that goes through every step and every window that I do always using hands from my browser.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I don't have an access to frontend app. All I have is the running app on my browser :)

Comment: What tech stack the FE app is built with? What are your prefs for the testing solution?

Comment: @ekostadinov FE app on Angular. Every step consist from different pages with different forms, I want to go through all of these pages with predefined data and see results.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with quizzes/wizards, such using gamification logic and transitioning from screen to screen - I had to properly plan my efforts.

> test that goes through every step and every window

Is easy to go way overboard with all possible paths, resulting in combinatorial explosion. As general advice, try limit the really critical scenarios and cover first those. It is quite likely that the conveyor engine, follows same basic (business) rules and just combines them to produce the flows. In other words, bugs are most likely to be found in the codified domain logic, than the mechanics behind them.

Since this is an Angular app and we all know how pesky [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/) is with it. I would go with [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) as it is built to handle

> native events and browser-specific drivers to interact with your application as a user would

and

> supports Angular-specific locator strategies

Comment: Interesting! Thanks, I will try it! And I will return here :)